# What does the following colon (:) mean in MATLAB syntax?

Tags: matlab, syntax, image-processing

```
a = imread('autumn.tif');
a = double(a); 
[row col dim] = size(a);
red = a(:, :, 1);
green = a(:, :, 2);
blue = a(:, :, 3);
```

What does the colon `:` in the last three lines mean? (The above snippet is from "Image Processing" by Dhananjay Theckedath.)

Comment: Try type 'MATLAB Help Colon' with google and you will come straight to the page describing it (MATLAB Help is very good!) http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`:`, in this context means 'all'.

```
red = a(:,:,1)
```

is equivalent to

```
red = a(1:end,1:end,1)
```

where `end` is automatically replaced by the number of elements in the respective dimension by Matlab.

So if `a` is a 23-by-55-by-3 array,

```
a(:,:,1)
```

is

```
a(1:23, 1:55, 1)
```

That means, this takes all rows, all columns from the first 'plane' of `a`. Since a RGB image is composed of a red, green, and a blue `plane` (in this order), `a(:,:,1)` is the red component of the image.

Comment: I don't understand that latter syntax either. :(

Comment: *slice* is perhaps not the best word in this scenario.  `x(5:10)` is a slice.  The set of elements sharing the third index is a *plane*.  Conveniently, much of the graphics literature also speaks of *color planes*.